# Gulpfile not found: ./gulpfile.js - even though it exists in Ionic 1

Tags: ionic-framework, gulp, command-line-interface

I recently updated Ionic CLI. I am trying to build an older application (v1 - created long ago) in this new cli version. But after installing gulp and running `ionic cordova build android` it shows following error. **But gulp file exists in that location.**

[image: Error image]

I tried uninstalling it but same issue.
This is my `Ionic info` - I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.

[image: Ionic info]

Comment: Update your ionic version, npm install -g ionic

Comment: Already tried this.

Comment: after that, give command npm install in your project path

Comment: Still same error

Comment: As my understanding issue of version difference. may be your machine ionic version is different and you project created version is different.
Ensure gulpfile.js or gulp.js

Comment: Yes, but how to make both compatible again?

Comment: Try with this to update your libraries. `ionic lib update`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to build Ionic 1 project, Then you should use
`cordova run android` This will run perfectly. and for release `cordova run android --release`

`ionic cordova build android` will work on Ionic 3 CLI.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered into the same problem, and after many unsuccessful tries, I added one line to `node_modules/@ionic/cli-plugin-gulp/index.js`:

```
if (e.code !== 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') {
     throw e;
}

console.dir(e); // ADD THIS

throw new cli_utils_1.FatalException(`Gulpfile not found: ${chalk.bold(cli_utils_1.prettyPath(gulpFilePath))}\n` +
                `You can set the ${chalk.bold('gulpFile')} attribute in ${chalk.bold(cli_utils_1.PROJECT_FILE)} for custom Gulpfile locations, otherwise the default Ionic Gulpfile can be downloaded from ${chalk.bold('https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-base/blob/master/gulpfile.js')}\n\n` +
                `Or, if you no longer use gulp, you can remove the CLI Gulp Plugin:\n\n` +
                `    ${chalk.green(gulpPluginUninstallArgs.join(' '))}`);
```

then run `ionic serve` again, the console can print out why it fails, we could try to resolve them now.

In my case, it's because of some missing gulp related packages (`gulp-bower gulp-minify-css gulp-rename gulp-concat`)